# Maximum of an integral

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Assume that $a>0$ and $r\in[0,1)$. How to prove that the function  $$f(p)=\int_{-\pi}^\pi \left (1+r^2+2 r \cos x\right)^{a/2} |(2+a) \cos(x+p)-a r \cos(p)| \, dx$$ attains its maximum for $p=\pi/2$?

Comment: It may help to know how this problem arose.

Comment: Note that $f(\pi/2)=2 r^{-1}[(1+r)^{a+2}-(1-r)^{a+2}]$, $f'(\pi/2)=0$ and $f''(\pi/2)=-f(\pi/2)<0$. In fact, all odd derivatives are zero, while the even ones oscillate between $\pm f(\pi/2)$...

Comment: ... the resulting candidate $f(p) = f(\pi/2) \sin p$, has, however, radius of convergence zero due to the branch cuts of the square root.

Comment: Welcome to MO.
This assumes a local maximum for all $a$ or all $r$ at $p = \pi/2$ so maybe differentiate under the integral sign with respect to $a$ or $r$ might help a little bit to show it is at least a local maximum ?